# rstandard vs stdres have different behaviour (the hat matrix)

Tags: r, regression, residuals, diagnostic

To obtain the standardized residuals in R, the the residuals minus their mean are divided by their standard deviation (calculated with the model degrees of freedom).
It is also calculated using the hat matrix.

rstandard (stats package) and stdres (MASS package) have a slight difference in their calculation:

- stdres uses only the positive values of the hat matrix. (https://github.com/cran/MASS/blob/c2ff394b1c45d58ebe72811699c683a3ca59e097/R/stdres.R). Line 21:

  `hat <- hat[hat > 0]`
- rtandard.lm uses all the values in the hat matrix (https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/lm.influence.R, line 110)

Thus when the hat matrix has negative values, R gives a warning (length of object differ), which is quite worrying.

Why do they behave differently regarding this? What is the reason to use only the positive values of the hat matrix?

Comment: Maybe the real question is "can a hat matrix have negative values?"

Comment: A hat matrix can have negative values but the diagonal should not.